# How to redirect with query string in Nginx for pagination

Tags: nginx

I would like to make a redirect from

```
https://www.example.com/blog?page=2
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/blog/page/2
```

I tried to use this configuration:

```
location = /blog {
    if ($args ~* “page=(.*)") {
        rewrite ^ /blog/page/$arg_page? permanent;
    }
}
```

It doesn't go to the second page (it stays at the first) and url is still `/blog?page=2`. So it doesn't work at all.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: That first double quote is not a double quote! But after fixing that, your code works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put `if` within `location` blocks, ever. This will lead to nothing but unexpected results.

The `if`s are quite safe in `server` context. However, this may not work either. Try:

```
server {
...
    if ($arg_page ~ "\d+") {
       rewrite ^/blog$ /blog/page/$arg_page? permanent;
    }
    ...
}
```

P.S. If you can use `map` for what `if` can do in a particular situation, then in general, you should use `map` only. (In your case you can't :)